# Address Sanitizer with SpriteKit

Tags: ios, xcode, sprite-kit, address-sanitizer

I'm trying to diagnose my app with Address Sanitizer. 
Although the app runs quite smoothly and I only wanted to get further checks regarding the memory alloc etc. I get the following error when I run the app. 
It's my first time using Address Sanitizer but as far as I concerened it needs to point out to one of the developer's line of code. 
It seems to me like it crashes at internal libary. 
Any ideas or suggestions?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently the problem was that I tried to run the game on an iPad with iOS8.0. 
On iOS >= 9.0 it works fine.